# whether merge and Reduce doing the same thing and all=True and by can reach the same goal

Tags: r

I am try to merge 4 data together. I tried `merge` and `reduce`. I wonder whether I am using them in the correct way. The outcome data seems like the same. I will need second eye to make sure I am not doing it wrong.

Here is my codes:

I used merge:

```
SUB_counts <- as_tibble(merge(count_pts, count_SUB, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)) 
SUB_counts_Re <- as_tibble(merge(count_pts_Re, count_SUB_Re, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)) 
SUB_counts_merge <- full_join(count_pts, count_SUB,  by = "SUBCOD")
```

and then I also tried `Reduce`:

```
test<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(count_pts, count_SUB, count_pts_Re, count_SUB_Re))
```

It looks like test=SUB_counts_merge

Could someone help me better understand those two?

1. when we use `all = TRUE`, is it same as use  `by = "SUBCOD"`?
2. when we use `Reduce`, there is no place to put 'by`, how can we know they are merged using the correct variable?

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `SUB_counts_merge` and `test` are the same.

For `SUB_counts_merge` you are following the process :

```
a = 1 + 2
b = 3 + 4
c = a + b
```

whereas for `test` the process that you are following is :

```
d = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

so obviously `c` and `d` are the same. But we also see that the process to obtain `d` is more easy and straightforward without any intermediate variables.

To answer your questions :

> 1. when we use all = TRUE, is it same as use  by = "SUBCOD"

No, they are not the same. If you are merging two dataframes `df1` and `df2`, `all = TRUE` is used to specify that all the rows in `df1` also all the rows in `df2` are kept. `by = "SUBCOD"` is used to specify the column that you want to merge on. Since you haven't explicitly specified the `by` argument here it will take the common columns in both the dataframe as `by` value. Also I would suggest to follow either base R syntax or `dplyr` whichever you find convenient. `merge` is a base R function whereas `full_join` is `dplyr`. When you specify `all = TRUE` that is base R way of saying to perform a full join whereas in `dplyr` we use `full_join`.

> 2. when we use Reduce, there is no place to put 'by`, how can we know they are merged using the correct variable?

There is a place as you have in normal `merge`. You can do

```
test<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by = "SUBCOD"), 
             list(count_pts, count_SUB, count_pts_Re, count_SUB_Re))
```